# 'I'm in favour of ___' vs. 'I'm for ___'

Tags: meaning, phrases, sentence, phrase-usage, flow

Is 'I'm in favour of' considered more formal than 'I'm for', or are they interchangeable? I want to say something like, 'Sometimes people abandon their logic /in favour of/ false hope', but can't help but feel that using 'for' would make the sentence more succinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in:

*Sometimes, people abandon their logic **for** false hope'*

**for**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/for)

> on behalf of; **in favor of**; because; since

As you see from the definition they are usually interchangeable.  And I agree with simplifying the sentence as you propose.